# ¿ Como cambio a base de datos dinámicamente ejecutando migraciones con Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un pequeño problemita, estoy realizando una conexión a  dos diferentes bases de datos, una que ya tengo creada y otra que genero de manera dinámica con migraciones. El problema es que al querer generar las tablas de la base dinámica me da el siguiente error:

**Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder.***

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
Config::set('database.connections.mydatabase.database', $dbname);
DB::connection('mydatabase');
Artisan::call('migrate', array('--path' => 'database/migrationscustom'));
```

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection('mydatabase')->create('tabclient', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->id('id');
            $table->string('name');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola Mira como puedes hacer:
Esas son las dos bases de datos que cree como puedes ver están sin tablas:
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Luego vengo y configuro el archivo

> config/databases.php

```
 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],

    'mysql_dinamica' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_DINAMICA', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

También configure el archivo de conexión .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=prueba
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123456

DB_CONNECTION=mysql_dinamica
DB_DATABASE_DINAMICA=prueba2
```

En las migraciones debes poner de la siguiente forma.

```
  Schema::connection('mysql')->create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('email')->index();
    $table->string('token');
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
});

 Schema::connection('mysql_dinamica')->create('failed_jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('uuid')->unique();
            $table->text('connection');
            $table->text('queue');
            $table->longText('payload');
            $table->longText('exception');
            $table->timestamp('failed_at')->useCurrent();
        });
```

Luego corres migraciones y listo:

> C:\laragon\www\PruebaNew
> λ php artisan migrate
> Migration table created successfully.
> Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
> Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (81.06ms)
> Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
> Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table (81.50ms)
> Migrating: 2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table
> Migrated:  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table (94.23ms)

Espero que te sirva esta pequeña guía. puedes igualmente correr migraciones archivos individuales.

Comment: @BetaM perdón ya lo cambie

Comment: Muchas gracias, ciertamente me ha funcionado tu respuesta Anwar Sarmiento.